# Different orientations of navbar even on using same stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem i am facing is in two different subpages of this webpage
[image: this is how i want it to look for all the subpages]

but in other pages say admission it looks like this

PS. I have removed the non-header part of the code from html as it was exceeding the word limits... Hope that wont be needed.

[image: admission.html]

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Delhi Public School</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="layout/styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/jquery.ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- Homepage Specific -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/galleryviewthemes/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/galleryviewthemes/jquery.timers.1.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/galleryviewthemes/jquery.galleryview.2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="layout/scripts/galleryviewthemes/jquery.galleryview.setup.js"></script>
<!-- / Homepage Specific -->
</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="wrapper row1">
  <div id="header" class="clear">
    <div class="fl_left">
      <h1><a href="index.html">School logo here</a></h1>
      <p>Insert the logo here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fl_right">
      <p><a href="#">A - Z Index</a> | <a href="#">Student Login</a> | <a href="#">Staff Login</a></p>
      <form action="#" method="post" id="sitesearch">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Site Search</legend>
          <input type="text" value="Search Our Website&hellip;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Search Our Website&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />
          <input type="image" src="layout/images/search.gif" id="search" alt="Search" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><div class="dropdown"><a href="index.html" class="dropbtn">Home</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li><div class="dropdown"><a href="pages/style-demo.html" class="dropbtn">About Us</a>
         <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li><div class="dropdown"><a href="pages/full-width.html" class="dropbtn">Admissions</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li><div class="dropdown"><a href="pages/3-columns.html" class="dropbtn">Rules</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li><div class="dropdown"><a href="pages/portfolio.html" class="dropbtn">Achievements</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li><div class="dropdown"><a href="pages/gallery.html" class="dropbtn">Gallery</a><div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li><div class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Information Coner</a><div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
        <li class="last"><div class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropbtn">Contact us</a><div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                 <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          </div>
          </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="iAmFixed">
  <a href="">Student Login...</a>

</div>
<div id="iAmFixedtoo">
  <a href="">Staff Login...</a>

</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
```

here is admission.html(full-width.html in )

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<!--
Template Name: Education Board
Author: <a href="http://www.os-templates.com/">OS Templates</a>
Author URI: http://www.os-templates.com/
Licence: Free to use under our free template licence terms
Licence URI: http://www.os-templates.com/template-terms
-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Education Board | Full Width</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../layout/styles/layout.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body id="top">
<div class="wrapper row1">
  <div id="header" class="clear">
    <div class="fl_left">
      <h1><a href="../index.html">Education Board</a></h1>
      <p>Free Website Template</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fl_right">
      <p><a href="#">A - Z Index</a> | <a href="#">Student Login</a> | <a href="#">Staff Login</a></p>
      <form action="#" method="post" id="sitesearch">
        <fieldset>
          <legend>Site Search</legend>
          <input type="text" value="Search Our Website&hellip;" onfocus="this.value=(this.value=='Search Our Website&hellip;')? '' : this.value ;" />
          <input type="image" src="../layout/images/search.gif" id="search" alt="Search" />
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>

  <div id="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li ><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="style-demo.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="full-width.html">Admissions</a></li>
        <li><a href="3-columns.html">Rules</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Achievements</a></li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Information Coner</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- ####################################################################################################### -->
```

here is the style sheet that affects the nav bar layout.css

```
@charset "utf-8";


@import url("navi.css");
@import url("forms.css");
@import url("tables.css");
@import url("homepage.css");
@import url("gallery.css");
@import url("portfolio.css");
@import url("featured_slide.css");


html{overflow-y:scroll;}
body{margin:0; padding:0; font-size:13px; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; color:#979797; background-color:#333333;}

#iAmFixed{
    background-color:yellow;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    bottom: 200px;
    padding:15px;
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    width:100px;
    z-index:10;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
#iAmFixedtoo{
    background-color:yellow;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    bottom: 250px;
    padding:15px;
    position:fixed;
    right:10px;
    width:120px;
    z-index:10;
        text-decoration:underline;

}
.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;

    padding: 12px 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #white;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #grey;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.justify{text-align:justify;}
.bold{font-weight:bold;}
.center{text-align:center;}
.right{text-align:right;}
.nostart{margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none;}

.clear:after{content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; line-height:0;}
.clear{display:inline-block;}
html[xmlns] .clear{display:block;}
* html .clear{height:1%;}

a{outline:none; text-decoration:none;}

.fl_left, .imgl{float:left;}
.fl_right, .imgr{float:right;}

img{margin:0; padding:0; border:none;}
.imgholder, .imgl, .imgr{padding:4px; border:1px solid #D8D8D8; text-align:center;}
.imgl{margin:0 15px 15px 0; clear:left;}
.imgr{margin:0 0 15px 15px; clear:right;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Wrapper------------------------------------- */

div.wrapper{display:block; width:100%; text-align:left;}
div.wrapper h1, div.wrapper h2, div.wrapper h3, div.wrapper h4, div.wrapper h5, div.wrapper h6{margin:0 0 15px 0; padding:0; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; font-style:italic; line-height:normal; color:white; background-color:transparent;}
.row1, .row2{color:white; background-color:transparent;}
.row3{color:#979797; background-color:#FFFFFF; border-top:1px solid #510000; border-bottom:5px solid #333333;}
.row3 a{color:#896C50; background-color:#FFFFFF;}
.row4{padding:30px 0;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Generalise------------------------------------- */

#header, #container, #footer, #copyright{display:block; position:relative; width:960px; margin:0 auto;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Header------------------------------------- */

#header{padding:25px 0 30px 0;}
#header h1, #header p, #header ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; line-height:normal;}
#header h1{font-size:26px; font-variant:small-caps; font-style:normal;}
#header h1 a{color:#ffffff; background-color:#333333;}
#header p{font-size:12px;}
#header p a{color:white ; background-color:#333333;}
#header .fl_left, #header .fl_right{margin-bottom:15px;}
#header .fl_right{margin-top:13px;}
#header .fl_right p{float:left; margin:5px 50px 0 0;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Content------------------------------------- */

#container{padding:30px 0; line-height:1.6em;}
#container h1, #container h2, #container h3, #container h4, #container h5, #container h6{background-color:#FFFFFF; margin:0 0 15px 0; padding:0 0 10px 0; border-bottom:1px solid #D8D8D8;}
#container .readmore{display:block; width:100%; text-align:right; line-height:normal;}
#content{display:block; float:left; width:630px;}

/* Comments */

#comments{margin-bottom:40px;}
#comments .commentlist{margin:0; padding:0;}
#comments .commentlist ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#comments .commentlist li.comment_odd, #comments .commentlist li.comment_even{margin:0 0 10px 0; padding:15px; list-style:none;}
#comments .commentlist li.comment_odd{color:#666666; background-color:#F7F7F7;}
#comments .commentlist li.comment_odd a{color:#896C50; background-color:#F7F7F7;}
#comments .commentlist li.comment_even{color:#666666; background-color:#E8E8E8;}
#comments .commentlist li.comment_even a{color:#896C50; background-color:#E8E8E8;}
#comments .commentlist .author .name{font-weight:bold;}
#comments .commentlist .submitdate{font-size:smaller;}
#comments .commentlist p{margin:10px 5px 10px 0; padding:0; font-weight:normal; text-transform:none;}
#comments .commentlist li .avatar{float:right; border:1px solid #EEEEEE; margin:0 0 0 10px;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Column------------------------------------- */

#column{display:block; float:right; width:300px;}
#column .holder, #column #featured{display:block; width:300px; margin-bottom:30px;}
#column .holder h2.title{display:block; width:100%; height:65px; margin:0; padding:15px 0 0 0; font-size:20px; text-transform:none; line-height:normal; border-bottom:1px dotted #999999;}
#column .holder h2.title img{float:left; margin:-15px 8px 0 0; padding:5px; border:1px solid #999999;}
#column div.imgholder{display:block; width:290px; margin:0 0 10px 0;}
#column .holder p.readmore{display:block; width:100%; font-weight:bold; text-align:right; line-height:normal;}

/* Featured Block */

#column #featured ul, #column #featured h2, #column #featured p{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; color:#666666; background-color:#F7F7F7;}
#column #featured a{color:#896C50; background-color:#F7F7F7;}
#column #featured li{display:block; width:250px; margin:0; padding:20px 25px; color:#666666; background-color:#F7F7F7;}
#column #featured li p.imgholder{display:block; width:240px; height:90px; margin:20px 0 15px 0;}
#column #featured li h2{margin:0; padding:0 0 8px 0; font-weight:normal; font-family:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; line-height:normal; border-bottom:1px dotted #999999;}
#container #column .readmore a{display:block; width:100%; margin-top:15px; height:auto; padding-left:0; font-weight:bold; text-align:right; line-height:normal; background:none;}
#column .latestnews{display:block; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#column .latestnews li{display:block; width:100%; height:99px; margin:0 0 11px 0; padding:0 0 21px 0; border-bottom:1px dotted #C7C5C8; overflow:hidden;}
#column .latestnews li.last, #column .last{margin-bottom:0;}
#column .latestnews p{display:inline;}
#column .latestnews img{float:left; margin:0 10px 0 0; padding:4px; border:1px solid #C7C5C8; clear:left;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Footer------------------------------------- */

#footer{line-height:1.6em; background:url("images/footer_bg.gif") 550px 0 repeat-y;}
#footer a{color:#979797; background-color:#333333;}
#footer h2{color:#FFFFFF; background-color:#333333; font-weight:bold; font-style:normal;}
#footer ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#footer address{font-style:normal;}
#footer .footbox{display:block; float:left; width:200px; margin-right:30px;}
#footer #social{margin-bottom:20px;}
#footer #social ul{margin:20px 0 0 0;}
#footer #social li{display:inline; margin-right:15px;}
#footer .last{margin:0;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Copyright------------------------------------- */

#copyright{padding:15px 0; border-top:1px solid #979797;}
#copyright p{margin:0; padding:0;}
#copyright, #copyright a{color:#979797; background-color:#333333;}
```

here is navi.css

```
@charset "utf-8";


#topnav{display:block; clear:both; width:960px; margin:0; padding:15px 0; text-align:center;}
#topnav, #topnav a{text-transform:uppercase; color:#FFFFFF; background-color:black;}
#topnav a:hover, #topnav li.active a{color:#c0c0c0; background-color:#33333;}
#topnav ul, #topnav li{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#topnav li{display:inline; margin-right:30px;}
#topnav li.last{margin:0;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Column Navigation------------------------------------- */

#column .subnav{display:block; width:250px; padding:25px; background-color:#F7F7F7; margin-bottom:30px; line-height:normal;}
#column .subnav h2{margin:0 0 20px 0; padding:0 0 14px 0; background-color:#F7F7F7; border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;}
#column .subnav ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
#column .subnav li{margin:0 0 3px 0; padding:0;}
#column .subnav ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul{border-top:none; padding-top:0;}
#column .subnav a{display:block; margin:0; padding:5px 10px 5px 20px; color:#666666; background:url("images/brown_file.gif") no-repeat 10px center #F7F7F7; text-decoration:none; border-bottom:1px dotted #666666;}
#column .subnav a:hover{color:#896C50; background-color:#F7F7F7;}
#column .subnav ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul a, #column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul a{background:url("images/black_file.gif") no-repeat #F7F7F7;}
#column .subnav ul ul a{padding-left:40px; background-position:30px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul a{padding-left:50px; background-position:40px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul ul a{padding-left:60px; background-position:50px center;}
#column .subnav ul ul ul ul ul a{padding-left:70px; background-position:60px center;}

/* ----------------------------------------------Pagination------------------------------------- */

.pagination{display:block; width:100%; clear:both; text-align:center;}
.pagination ul{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none;}
.pagination li{display:inline;}
.pagination .next{margin:0;}
.pagination a{display:inline-block; margin:0 2px 0 0; padding:2px 5px 3px 5px; border:1px solid #D8D9DE;}
.pagination .current, .pagination .splitter{margin:0 2px 0 0; padding:6px;}
.wrapper .pagination a:hover, .pagination .current, .pagination .splitter{color:#000000; background-color:#EBEDEE;}
```

Comment: is the same stylesheet being used across all pages? Any inline style?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: @RachelGallen no inline style sheet same everywhere..

Comment: @GokulanPH will git link work havent used fiddle so have no idea about it

Comment: @RohitJaiswal go to http://www.jsfiddle.net ; you can create a free account (handy if you want to save your work) or just create a fiddle on the fly without an account. Add in external resources using the left hand sidebar (e.g. links to jquery etc. ) There are panels for html/javascript/css. When you run it you will see the output in the bottom right,